# EntityFrameworkCore PostgreSQL Left Join with where not working

Tags: c#, postgresql, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to perform a left join using Entity Framework Core, but it creates a subquery in the join that doesn't work.

I created a [sample project](https://pastebin.com/a7H65bvb) to illustrate the problem

This is my Linq query which selects all streams from an account and the subscribers during that stream

Linq query syntax

```
    from account in context.Accounts
    where account.Id == 6
    join steam in context.Streams on account.Id equals steam.AccountId
    join subscription in context.Subscriptions on account.Id equals subscription.TargetAccountId into
        groupJoin
    from subscription in groupJoin.Where(subscription => subscription.Date > steam.StreamStart && subscription.Date < steam.StreamEnd).DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new {account, steam, subscription};
```

Linq extention method syntax

```
    context.Accounts.Where(account => account.Id == 6)
        .Join(context.Streams, outer => outer.Id, inner => inner.AccountId,
        (account, stream) => new { Account = account, Stream = stream })
        .GroupJoin(context.Subscriptions, outer => outer.Account.Id, inner => inner.TargetAccountId,
        (outer, subscriptions) => new
        { Account = outer.Account, Stream = outer.Stream, Subscriptions = subscriptions })
        .SelectMany(x =>
            x.Subscriptions.Where(subscription =>
                    subscription.Date > x.Stream.StreamStart && subscription.Date < x.Stream.StreamEnd)
                .DefaultIfEmpty(),
        (x, subscription) => new { x.Account, x.Stream, Subscription = subscription }).ToList();
```

This is the query that gets generated

```
    SELECT account."Id", account."Name", stream."Id", stream."AccountId", stream."StreamEnd", stream."StreamStart", stream."Title", t."SourceAccountId", t."TargetAccountId", t."Date"
          FROM "Accounts" AS account
          INNER JOIN "Streams" AS stream ON account."Id" = stream."AccountId"
          LEFT JOIN (
              SELECT "inner"."SourceAccountId", "inner"."TargetAccountId", "inner"."Date"
              FROM "Subscriptions" AS "inner"
              WHERE ("inner"."Date" > stream."StreamStart") AND ("inner"."Date" < stream."StreamEnd")
          ) AS t ON account."Id" = t."TargetAccountId"
          WHERE account."Id" = 6
```

Which gives me the following error

> Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42P01: invalid reference to
>   FROM-clause entry for table "stream"

Is my Linq query wrong or is this a bug/limitation in Entity Framework?

Comment: Bug/limitation. What EF Core are you using (to see if it's fixed in later version or how to workaround it)?

Comment: I'm using Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 2.2.4

Comment: Note: try to avoid the reserved/key words (Date, inner) Even if Postgres allows them, your framework may get triggered by them.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely EF Core query translation bug - reproduces with the latest EF Core 2.2.6 and also SqlServer provider, so it's not Npgsql provider specific.

Since 3.0 will use totally rewritten query translator, and in the current preview many things don't function properly, it can't be said if it would be fixed there or not.

The workaround is to move the correlated filter outside the `join` (with additional `null` check to account for `left outer join` introduced by `DefaultIfEmpty()`):

```
var result = context.Accounts
    .Where(account => account.Id == 6)
    .Join(context.Streams, outer => outer.Id, inner => inner.AccountId,
        (account, stream) => new { Account = account, Stream = stream })
    .GroupJoin(context.Subscriptions, outer => outer.Account.Id, inner => inner.TargetAccountId,
        (outer, subscriptions) => new
        { Account = outer.Account, Stream = outer.Stream, Subscriptions = subscriptions })
    .SelectMany(x => x.Subscriptions.DefaultIfEmpty(),
        (x, subscription) => new { x.Account, x.Stream, Subscription = subscription })
    .Where(x => x.Subscription == null || (
        x.Subscription.Date > x.Stream.StreamStart &&
        x.Subscription.Date < x.Stream.StreamEnd))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: But this doesn't include the streams that have no Subscriptions, because in the group join every subscription is added (because there is no date check) and the where filters them out. So the x.Subscription == null is obsolete

Comment: No, it's not (at least this is what your query would do if was working). The original query does include them because of the `DefaultIfEmpty()` after `Where` condition. Basically this does left outer join. If you don't need that, remove `DefaultIfEmpty` (this will turn the join to inner) and null check).

Comment: But there might be a difference if all the subscriptions are outside the date range. I have no idea how to workaround that case.

Comment: The `.Where(x => x.Subscription == null` is only usefull if there are 0 subscribtions to the account. Because there is no time check in the join, every subscribtion will end up in the join.

Comment: And this is possible scenario, right? Personally I'm more concerned for the other case I mentioned in the previous comment, which is not handled here.

Comment: If all the subscriptions are outside the date range nothing gets returned.
To work around the issue I'm going to run 2 queries. and hopefully, replace that when Dotnet core 3 stable is released